# Traduction de « timestamp »

Tags: traduction, informatique, terminologie, demande-de-mot

J'aimerais savoir si on peut traduire « time stamp » par « plage horaire » ? J'ai vu sur des sites que plage horaire se traduirait par « time slot » mais je trouve que dans un certain contexte c'est mieux de dire « time stamp ». J'essaye de trouver les différences ou s'il y a un mot en français plus approprié pour les deux.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Un time stamp est un instant précis et non une plage horaire.

Le terme qui s'en rapproche le plus en français est "Horodatage".

> [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horodatage) :
>
> L'horodatage (en anglais timestamping) est un mécanisme qui consiste à associer une date et une heure à un événement, une information ou une donnée informatique. Il a généralement pour but d'enregistrer l'instant auquel une opération a été effectuée.
>
> La valeur représentant la date et l'heure est appelée timestamp (de l'anglais time, « heure » et stamp, marquage par un timbre ou un tampon) ou tout simplement « horodatage ».

Comment: En developpement informatique: Le timestamp (unix) désigne le nombre de secondes écoulées depuis le 1er janvier 1970 à minuit UTC précise ([source](http://www.timestamp.fr/?)). Il définit donc un instant précis, même s'il représente la différences entre 2 instants (ce qui je pense porte la confusion)